# what is it that i am doing wrong while converting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i need to convert this mysql into pdo i tried the following but i guess its wrong as i get no results showing. yes it may be easy for one of you but pdo is news to me so appreciate your help :)

actual code

```
$rowperpage = 3;

            // counting total number of posts
            $allcount_query = "SELECT count(*) as allcount FROM posts";
            $allcount_result = mysql_query($allcount_query);
            $allcount_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($allcount_result);
            $allcount = $allcount_fetch['allcount'];

            // select first 3 posts
            $query = "select * from posts order by id asc limit 0,$rowperpage ";
            $result = mysql_query($query);

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $content = $row['content'];
                $shortcontent = substr($content, 0, 160)."...";
                $link = $row['link'];

            ?>
                <!-- Post -->
                <div class="post" id="post_<?php echo $id; ?>">
                    <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $shortcontent; ?>
                    </p>
                    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="more" target="_blank">More</a>
                </div>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

what i tried

```
 $rowperpage = 3;

        // counting total number of posts
        //$allcount_query = "SELECT count(*) as allcount FROM posts";
        //$allcount_result = mysql_query($allcount_query);

        $query = "SELECT count(*) FROM posts";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);       



        $allcount_fetch = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $allcount = $stmt->fetchColumn();

        // select first 3 posts
        //$query = "select * from posts order by id asc limit 0,$rowperpage ";
        //$result = mysql_query($query);

        $qry = "select * from posts order by id asc limit 0,$rowperpage ";
        $stm = $db->prepare($qry);  

        while($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            $id = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $content = $row['content'];
            $shortcontent = substr($content, 0, 160)."...";
            $link = $row['link'];
```

can someone show the right way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501608/i-want-to-convert-a-mysql-query-into-pdo

Comment: start your PDO from here http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Do some proper debugging, and find out why your modified script is not working yourself. This includes you reading up on what the common debug methods when using PDO are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to convert a MySQL query into PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501608/i-want-to-convert-a-mysql-query-into-pdo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prepare()` goes with `execute()`

Prepared statements basically work like this:

1. Prepare: An SQL statement template is created and sent to the
   database. Certain values are left unspecified, called parameters
   (labeled "?"). Example:

   `INSERT INTO mtTable VALUES(?, ?, ?)`
2. The database parses, compiles, and performs query optimization on
   the SQL statement template, and stores the result without executing
   it
3. Execute: At a later time, the application binds the values to the
   parameters, and the database executes the statement. The application
   may execute the statement as many times as it wants with different
   values

try with below code

```
<?php

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$rowperpage = 3;
$offset     = 0;

// counting total number of posts
$query = "SELECT count(id) AS allcount  FROM posts";
$stmt  = $db->query($query)->fetchColumn();

/******** The ABOVE QUERY LOOKS POINTLESS TO ME AS YOU NOT USING THE RESULTS FROM THAT QUERY*/

// select first 3 posts

$qry = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ?,? ";
$stm = $db->prepare($qry);
$stm->execute(array($offset,$rowperpage));
$results = $stm->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (count($results) > 0) {

    foreach ($results as $row) {

        $id           = $row['id'];
        $title        = $row['title'];
        $content      = $row['content'];
        $shortcontent = substr($content, 0, 160) . "...";
        $link         = $row['link'];

    }
} else {

    echo "No records found";
}
?>
```

Comment: works like charm really appreciated mate thanks a ton. lots of blessings to you :)

Comment: @ChristineMay pls mind your manners, you can ask for clarification in a nicer way. The place to ask is meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: not sure whats going on @Shadow just loging in know.. anyway thanks for the commen

Comment: @ChristineMay the problem is with your question that it is not specific enough ("too broad") and the community in general does not like such questions. Obviously, it does not mean that nobody will answer such a question. Why is your question too broad? Because in the question you just dump the code basically saying "it does not work". Here on SO you are expected to do some basic debugging yourself and come up with an error message or mode detailed error description. We discourage users asking questions like this by closing them.

Comment: if the site is for help whats wrong in asking a question? i did not spam or posted anything wrong other than asking for help in something i was not being able to do it. trust me with such attitude and rules one day people will stop using this site.